# mySQL using python: Select case sensitive fields using BINARY produces syntax error

Tags: python, mysql, select, collate

Goal: **selecting all fields `body` from a database `DB` that contain the word 'Target' exactly (i.e., case sensitive)**.

In in python3 (after importing *pandas* and *sqlite3*) I am using:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("/Users/Desktop/DB.sqlite")

c = conn.cursor()

res = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT body,date FROM DB "
                        "WHERE body LIKE BINARY '%Target%' LIMIT 10000",conn)

conn.close()
```

This produces a syntax error " *near the "'Target'"* ".

I also tried using `COLLATE` with the following syntax:

```
res = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT body,date FROM DB "
                        "WHERE body LIKE '%Target%' COLLATE utf8_bin LIMIT 10000",conn)
```

No error is thrown, but the match is not case sensitive.

Any help?

Comment: Could you try like this ? ` WHERE body LIKE _utf8 '%Target%' COLLATE utf8_bin `

Comment: Hi Thomas - no, the following error is produced:
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT body,date FROM DB WHERE body LIKE _utf8 '%Target%' COLLATE utf8_bin LIMIT 10000': near "'%Target%'": syntax error